# How to Hide Cash On Delivery In OneStepCheckout On base of Shipping Postal Code

Tags: event-observer, overrides, payment-methods

I want to hide Cash On Delivery On base Of Shipping Postal Code....
I m Using One OneStepCheckout....
I used Payment Observer

```
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>checkdelivery/observer</class>
                <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
        </events> 

Code
----------------
 public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
         if($observer->getEvent()->getQuote() && ($observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getId())):
        /* call get payment method */
        $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
        $method = $observer->getData('result');
        $methodInstance = $observer->getData('method_instance');
        $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();
        $pindata = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
        $pincodearray = explode(",", $pindata);
        $trimedZip = $billAddress->getPostcode();
        $cartItems = $checkout->getAllItems();

        //$totalCartItem = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
        //$condition = array();
        if ($methodInstance->getCode() == 'cashondelivery') { //if method is cache on delivery
                if (!in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {//if  post pin not matched to given pin
                    $method->isAvailable = false;
                }
            }
    return;
        endif;      

    }
```

It s Hide Payment Method ..When OneStepCheckout Is Loading....
But Here One Step checkout Is Updating Every Time When You Change Pin....
Its Uses Ajax...
Basically I want to hide COD...In One Step....
So Finally I Want Rewrite Model Of Payment Method....
I want To know that which Model Have All Details Of Payment Method....
How to Do this.....